# Pandas DataFrame Assignment Bug using Dictionaries of Strings and Floats?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-loc

### Problem

Pandas seems to support using `df.loc` to assign a dictionary to a row entry, like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'])
entry = {'a':'test', 'b':1, 'c':float(2)}
df.loc[0] = entry
```

As expected, Pandas inserts the dictionary values to the corresponding columns based on the dictionary keys. Printing this gives:

```
      a  b    c
0  test  1  2.0
```

However, if you overwrite the same entry, Pandas will assign the dictionary *keys* instead of the dictionary values. Printing this gives:

```
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

### Question

Why does this happen?

Specifically, why does this ***only* happen** on the second assignment? All subsequent assignments revert to the original result, containing (*almost*) the expected values:

```
      a  b  c
0  test  1  2
```

I say almost because the `dtype` on `c` is actually an `object` instead of `float` for all subsequent results.

---

I've determined that this happens whenever there is a string and a float involved. You won't find this behavior if it's just a string and integer, or integer and float.

### Example Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c'])
print(f'empty df:\n{df}\n\n')

entry = {'a':'test', 'b':1, 'c':float(2.3)}
print(f'dictionary to be entered:\n{entry}\n\n')

df.loc[0] = entry
print(f'df after entry:\n{df}\n\n')

df.loc[0] = entry
print(f'df after second entry:\n{df}\n\n')

df.loc[0] = entry
print(f'df after third entry:\n{df}\n\n')

df.loc[0] = entry
print(f'df after fourth entry:\n{df}\n\n')
```

This gives the following printout:

```
empty df:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []


dictionary to be entered:
{'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': float(2)}


df after entry:
      a  b    c
0  test  1  2.0


df after second entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c


df after third entry:
      a  b  c
0  test  1  2


df after fourth entry:
      a  b  c
0  test  1  2
```

Comment: Interesting find. On pandas version `1.2.4`, _all_ the subsequent dataframes have the value `a b c`, not just the second one.

Comment: @aneroid even if you wrap in `pd.Series()` ?

Comment: @rudolfovic Wrapping it in a series removes the problem. But I'm not concerned with the workaround. The expected behaviour is not the observed behaviour. `df.loc[0] = entry.values()` also works but that's - again - a workaround. It only seems to work correctly when assigning to a new row.

Comment: Reproducible in version `1.1.5`, so something has been changed somewhere between `1.1.5` and `1.2.4`.

Comment: The documentation does not say anywhere that you could pass a dictionary.

Comment: I think this should become an issue on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The 1.2.4 behaviour is as follows:

```
empty df:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []


dictionary to be entered:
{'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': 2.3}


df after entry:
      a  b    c
0  test  1  2.3


df after second entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c


df after third entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c


df after fourth entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

The first time `df.loc[0]` the function is the [`_setitem_with_indexer_missing`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#LC1922) function is run since there is no index `0` on the axis:

This line is run:

```
elif isinstance(value, dict):
    value = Series(
        value, index=self.obj.columns, name=indexer, dtype=object
    )
```

Which turns the `dict` into a series and it behaves as expected.

---

In future times, however, since the index is not missing (there exists an index `0`) [`_setitem_with_indexer_split_path`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#LC1685) is run:

```
elif len(ilocs) == len(value):
    # We are setting multiple columns in a single row.
    for loc, v in zip(ilocs, value):
        self._setitem_single_column(loc, v, pi)
```

This just zips the column locations with the each value from the `dict`:

In this case that's something roughly equivalent to:

```
entry = {'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': float(2.3)}
print(list(zip([0, 1, 2], entry)))
# [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Hence why the values are the keys.

---

For this reason, the problem isn't as specific as it may seem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(f'df:\n{df}\n\n')

entry = {'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': float(2.3)}
print(f'dictionary to be entered:\n{entry}\n\n')

df.loc[0] = entry
print(f'df after entry:\n{df}\n\n')
```

```
initial df:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3

dictionary to be entered:
{'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': 2.3}

df after entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

If the index loc exists it will not convert to a series: it simply zips the column locs with the iterable. In the case of the dictionary this means the keys are the values that get included in the frame.

This is also likely the reason why **only** iterables whose iterators return their **values** are acceptable left-hand arguments to `loc` assignment.

---

I also concur with [@DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626080/pandas-dataframe-assignment-bug-using-dictionaries-of-strings-and-floats/67626737#comment119533058_67626080) that this should be raised as a bug.

---

## The 1.1.5 Behaviour is as follows:

The initial assignment is unchanged from 1.2.4 however:

The dtypes are noteable here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3]}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

entry = {'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': float(2.3)}

# First Entry
df.loc[0] = entry
print(df.dtypes)
# a     object
# b     object
# c    float64
# dtype: object

# Second Entry
df.loc[0] = entry
print(df.dtypes)
# a    object
# b    object
# c    object
# dtype: object

# Third Entry
df.loc[0] = entry
print(df.dtypes)
# a    object
# b    object
# c    object
# dtype: object

# Fourth Entry
df.loc[0] = entry
print(df.dtypes)
# a    object
# b    object
# c    object
# dtype: object
```

The reason they are notable is because when

```
take_split_path = self.obj._is_mixed_type
```

is true. It does the same zip thing that it does in 1.2.4.

However, in 1.1.5 The dtypes are all `object` so `take_split_path` is only false after the first assignment since `c` is `float64`. Subsequent assignments use:

```
if isinstance(value, (ABCSeries, dict)):
    # TODO(EA): ExtensionBlock.setitem this causes issues with
    # setting for extensionarrays that store dicts. Need to decide
    # if it's worth supporting that.
    value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
```

Which, naturally, aligns the `dict` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting find. On pandas version `1.2.4`, *all* the subsequent dataframes have the value `a b c`, not just the second one.

```
empty df:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []

dictionary to be entered:
{'a': 'test', 'b': 1, 'c': 2.3}

df after entry:
      a  b    c
0  test  1  2.3

df after second entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c

df after third entry:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
```

Btw, it only seems to work correctly when assigning to a *new* row. So it's only associating the keys with the columns in that situation. For all subsequent re-assigning to existing rows, it has the observed unexpected behaviour, in `1.2.4`.

```py
df.loc[1] = entry
print(f'df after assigning to a new row:\n{df}\n\n')
# output:
df after assigning to a new row:
      a  b    c
0     a  b    c
1  test  1  2.3

df.loc[1] = entry
print(f'df after reapting:\n{df}\n')
# output:
df after reapting:
   a  b  c
0  a  b  c
1  a  b  c
```

The reason it may be happening for existing rows (apart from being a bug) is that **it's *iterating over the collection*. In the case of dictionaries, it's the keys.**
In the docs section "[Setting with enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement)"

> The `.loc/[]` operations can perform enlargement when setting a non-existent key for that axis.
>
> In the `Series` case this is effectively an appending operation.

So for new rows, it's "enlarging" the input but for existing rows, it's iterating over the input (keys for dicts, not values).

For a list, it woks as one would expect.

```py
df.loc[2] = list(entry.values())
print(f'df when assigning from a list\n{df}\n')
# output
df when assigning from a list
      a  b    c
0     a  b    c
1     a  b    c
2  test  1  2.3


df.loc[2] = list(entry.values())
print(f'df when assigning from a list 2nd time\n{df}\n')
# output
df when assigning from a list 2nd time
      a  b    c
0     a  b    c
1     a  b    c
2  test  1  2.3
```

(That's the *why* based on the docs. I think the actual technical reason may only be apparent after perusing the source code.)

Imho, it should either work for all assignments/re-assignemnts or not be allowed at all. I agree that this should be raised as a bug, as [@DeepSpace mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626080/pandas-dataframe-assignment-bug-using-dictionaries-of-strings-and-floats/67626737#comment119533058_67626080).